# Changing property on WPF control in another application?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

Is it possible to change a value of a WinRT control in another application?

I am using a Windows Surface Pro 2, which uses Windows 8.1. this OS has a text prediction feature which requires the `TextBox.IsTextPredictionEnabled` property to be set to true.  If this is set to false, then it will not use the text prediction.

Unfortunately for me, there are instances where the application developer thought it prudent to turn this feature off (default is on) and I disagree. I would like to change this. Is there a way?

Comment: (If it's using the Windows runtime, it's not using WPF -- it's using either WinJS/HTML or XAML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The applications on top of WinRT are heavily sandboxed, so there is no direct way to affect other applications than yours.

Comment: Guess that makes sense for security purposes... otherwise I could be quite nefarious. So aside from finding another program, or rewriting it myself, I'm screwed?

Comment: @MikeChristiansen Well, there is always option of contacting creator of the app and asking if they can't add settings option for it.

Comment: Microsoft. I want prediction on my address bar for IE. Well, actually EVERYTHING

Answer (score 1):

As Euphoric said, there is no direct way to do that.

If I needed to change a properties (I'm talking about our own apps), maybe I can try to create a text file and read it with the other app, so with a few if condition I can change values by that text file. But both of your applications should be updated. If they are not our application there is no way to do that.